# Is the electric field arrangement in photon fixed?

Tags: photons, electric-fields

When we measure a photon's electric field (let's take a visible light photon) then do we observe the electric field's direction first, let's say, upwards then downwards?
Or is the detection of both electric fields' probability 50-50% when that photon enters the detector?

Comment: Photons don't have an electric field. Could it be that you had spin in mind? Then this might be relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288105/entangled-photons-spin-switch

Answer (score 2):

In a single photon state, the expectation value of the electric field is zero, although fluctuations are not zero. It is required  a coherent state of photons in order to have an electric field with the same properties as macroscopic fields.

Answer (score 0):

As per our currently accepted theory, the Standard Model, the photon is an elementary particle, it is electromagnetically neutral, it does not have an EM charge, it is a point particle, it does not have a spatial extension or an internal structure.

It is very important to differentiate between the near and far field.

> > The far field is the region in which the field acts as "normal" electromagnetic radiation. In this region, it is dominated by electric or magnetic fields with electric dipole characteristics. The near field is governed by multipole type fields, which can be considered as collections of dipoles with a fixed phase relationship.
> >
> > In the far-field region, each part of the EM field (electric and magnetic) is "produced by" (or associated with) a change in the other part, and the ratio of electric and magnetic field intensities is simply the wave impedance. However, in the near-field region, the electric and magnetic fields can exist independently of each other, and one type of field can dominate the other.

A photon does not create its own EM field around itself(I am talking about the near field). Though, the photon is the mediator of the EM interaction.

I believe what you are confusing the particle with, is the electron. The electron is an elementary particle (you can call it an elementary charge), and does create an EM field (near field) around itself.

Now this EM field (near field) is what you are talking about, and in the mathematical description of this field, we use a mathematical model, called virtual photons to describe the interaction between the EM field (created by the electron) and another particle that is interacting with it. But this is a virtual particle, and is just a mathematical model.

I believe what you are asking about is the real photon, and that does not create an EM field (near field) around itself, it is electromagnetically neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Classically, radiation comes from accelerating charges. A single photon would be the radiation from one charge, usually in one atom or at least one molecule.

The charge would get accelerated in some trajectory, and that would cause radiation while it was being accelerated.

An electron that got accelerated while it went from one "orbital" to another, might be moving in a spiral or something like that, and that would give you a temporary wave.

But we can't detect individual electrons moving back and forth in atoms or molecules. it's all hypothetical. If we instead look at all the possible things that might be going on, and the probabilities that they happen, and average that all together, then we get a sort of probabilistic photon to go with our probabilistic atom.

If we were talking about a hypothetical electron getting accelerated, then we could exactly predict the direction of force of the radiation field at each point in space at each time. But when we talk about a probabilistic photon coming from a probabilistic atom, the direction of force could be anything -- at some probability.